# fancy indexing in pytorch?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

how to reach the same tensor without the looping

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

batch = 1
embd_dim = 768
num_groups = 50
num_elements = 19

embedding_matrix = torch.randn(num_elements, num_groups, embd_dim)

tensor_shape = (batch , num_elements, embd_dim)
indexing_tensor = torch.randint(0, 50, tensor_shape)

print(f"{indexing_tensor.shape = }")
print(f"{embedding_matrix.shape = }")
# print(f"{}")


temp_batch = [0] * len(indexing_tensor)
for batch_index , bat in enumerate(indexing_tensor):
    tep_t = [0] * len(bat)
    for n , ii in enumerate(bat):
        emb0 = embedding_matrix[n][ii]
        tep_t[n] = emb0
        
    temp_batch[batch_index] = torch.stack(tep_t)
tensor = torch.stack(temp_batch)

tensor.shape
```

In the realm of code, where queries unfold,
Lies Stack Overflow, with tales untold.
A kingdom vast, where programmers unite,
Yet governed by rules, often a plight.

Arbitrary laws, like lines of code,
Syntax strict, in a rigid abode.
Asking and answering, a dance so divine,
But tangled in rules, the brilliance can decline.

Oh, Stack Overflow, with your points and score,
A hierarchy of knowledge, we adore.
Yet in the shadows, arbitrary and cold,
Lurk rules that puzzle, stories untold.

Syntax, a language, in a realm so vast,
Yet enforced by laws, unforgiving and fast.
Mismatched brackets and typos unseen,
Invoke the wrath of rules so keen.